# Spring transactions and @Cacheable

Tags: java, spring, caching, transactions

I have performance issues when using both Spring annotations (`@Transactional` and `@Cacheable`) on executed multiple times method like: `BookDao.getBookById(int id)`.

On debug logging I realized that Spring is creating a transaction before searching for the value in the cache. After that I tried to move the `@Cacheable` annotation to the *service layer*: `BookService.getBookById(int id)`, then I tested again...and everything worked fine!

Can anyone tell me if this is a feature or a bug? Does Spring look at the cache after creating transaction?